# Using Eclipse Android Debugger with a Custom Makefile Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I've been building my Android project using my own build system. The build system I am using involves makefiles that merges code between several Android projects. I want to move into using eclipse to develop and build my application.

If you are wondering why I am merging several Android projects together: I have several versions of an application I am building that uses a common code base that is in a separate Android project. Since the differences between the version of the application are aesthetics, each version has their own res files that override the res files from the shared library code.

With that said, is there a way to use eclipse to build the project with the custom makefiles that I have and be able to take advantage of the debugger tool in eclipse?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've always found the native stuff is best done out of eclipse and I just use eclipse to build / debug the gui. Although you can get the native stuff to log so that its visible in logcat.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The reason why I want to do this is so that I can take advantage of the debugger and ADT through the eclipse interface. I am able to develop because I referenced all the dependencies.